# Two requests, same destination IP, different gateway

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

I have 3 routers connected to my local network. Each router has a unique external IP address which is dynamic. I use cUrl to send a request to the dynamic DNS service provider in order to keep up with IP changes.

What I need is to be able to send 3 different requests from the same computer and each of those, be routed through the 3 different gateways. Operating system is Windows Server 2012. Is there a way to bypass the default gateway of the network adapter for a single request?